# SQL Query: Joining two tables where entity of the first table has no, or multiple entries in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have to database tables, where entities of the first Table may or may not have associated entries in the second table:

```
Table 1          Table 2       
+-----+-----+    +-----+-------+-------+
| ID  | ... |    | ID  | T1_ID | NAME  |
+-----+-----+    +-----+-------+-------+
|  1  | ... |    |  1  |   1   |  p1   |
|  2  | ... |    |  2  |   1   |  p2   |
|  3  | ... |    |  3  |   2   |  p1   |
|  4  | ... |    +-----+-------+-------+
+-----+-----+
```

I have the following queries i need to run:

1. Get all entities of Table_1 with a specific entry of Table_2 - That's easy, a simple Join will do...
2. Get all entities of Table_1, which don't have a specific entry of Table_2 associated - not so easy, but i also managed to query this with a join.
3. Get all entities of Table_1, which have a specific entry (A) and don't have another specific entry (B) associated, i.e. get all entities of Table_1 that have an entity of Table_2 with name=p1 and don't have an entity of Table_2 with name=p2 associated.

Is it possible to accomplish the kind of query from (3) in a single sql-statement without a sub-query?

Comment: This is not a forum to "get others to do your job for you". If you want to do that however, the least you can do is give sample data and sample desired output.

Comment: well, in the simplest case, i would just like to get the corresponding IDs of Table 1. Is my sample data above not sufficient?

Comment: @ user655145, can you share the query for point 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` subquery (effectively the same as doing two joins).

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_2 AS t2 WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id AND Name='p1')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_2 AS t2 WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id AND Name='p2')
```

Answer (score 4):

> Get all entities of Table_1, which
>   have a specific entry (A) and don't
>   have another specific entry (B)
>   associated, i.e. get all entities of
>   Table_1 that have an entity of Table_2
>   with name=p1 and don't have an entity
>   of Table_2 with name=p2 associated.

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your criteria, but I think that is what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.t1_id 
WHERE t2.name = 'p1' 
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'x' FROM Table2 t2_2 WHERE t1.ID = t2_2.t1_id AND t2_2.name = 'p2')
```

That will give you everything from Table1 that has a matching record in Table2 with name = 'p1' and DOESN'T have a matching record in Table2 with name = 'p2'. Is that what you need?

**EDIT AGAIN:**

I thought of a smarter way to do this that involves a static (non-correlated) subquery. This subquery will only be executed one time, rather than being executed once for every parent row in Table1. I didn't put this code through a query analyzer, but it should be significantly faster than of the queries using EXISTS(...)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.t1_id 
WHERE t2.name = 'p1' 
AND t1.id NOT IN(SELECT t1_id FROM Table2 WHERE name = 'p2')
```

Comment: yeah, that's more or less what i want, however, i was wondering if something like that was possible without subqueries... Sorry for the inaccuracy.

Comment: @donneo I added a second query that just uses joins. It COULD be faster than the version that uses subqueries, if your indexes are set up correctly, but it's hard to say without test data.

Comment: @ean5533 Yeah, i came to a simliar "double" join myself, but still i don't get the correct result with that approach... :-(

Comment: @donneo Can you give an example of when this doesn't work? I'm fairly certain those queries will give you what you asked for, but you may be asking the wrong question. List some sample data in your question, and then show examples of what data the query should return.

Comment: @ean5533 i tried to break my tables down to the most basic fields, i can only say, if i translate your proposal back to my real tables, i still get a result that has 'p1' but also has 'p2'... ;(

Comment: @donneo You're right, my apologies, that second query won't work. I've removed it from my answer. You'll have to use a NOT EXISTS subquery to get what you want.

Comment: @donneo A better idea came to me last night. See if the query I added to my answer does any better for you.

Comment: @ean5533 I was under the impression, that subqueries are executed for every resulting row of the outer query? Now i don't know about "static subqueries", but your above example looks like a regular subquery to me, or do i miss something here?

Comment: @donneo Well it depends on how the server's query optimizer works, but all major DBMS optimizers are smart enough to look at a subquery and determine that its results are never going to change. "Static subquery" may not be the correct term, but that's the idea. If you look at the subquery, you'll see that it doesn't reference anything from the main query, so there's no need to execute it more than once. Most optimizers are smart enough to notice that and execute it once, then cache the results. Oracle, MySQL, and MS SQL Server all definitely do it.

Answer (score 0):

To get all occurrences where t2 matches t1.id but not some other field do

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON (t2.t1_id = t1.id AND not(t2.fieldx <=> t1.fieldx))
```

Note that this will also exclude rows where both `fieldx` are `null`.
If you don't want that substitute the `<=>` with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

To make the variation of solutions more complete:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table_1 t1
  INNER JOIN Table_2 it2 ON t1.ID = it2.T1_ID AND it2.NAME = 'p1'
  LEFT JOIN Table_2 lt2  ON t1.ID = lt2.T1_ID AND lt2.NAME = 'p2'
WHERE lt2.ID IS NULL
```